# SQL Join with 2 conditions in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to find out how many users from May table have their roles updated/changed in January. January table can have additional users but I don't care about them at this point.

Both tables have ony two fields ROLEUSER and ROLENAME, and they look like this:

```
ROLEUSER   ROLENAME
abc123     admin
abc123     reader
abc123     writer
cde456     reader
cde456     writer
```

I tried:

```
SELECT Jan.ROLEUSER, Jan.ROLENAME
FROM Jan INNER JOIN 
May ON Jan.ROLEUSER = May.ROLEUSER
AND Jan.ROLENAME <> May.ROLENAME
```

Comment: Can you add sample data for both Jan and May and what you want to see in the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT Jan.ROLEUSER, Jan.ROLENAME
  FROM Jan
  WHERE NOT Exists (
    SELECT * FROM May where
    Jan.ROLEUSER = MAY.ROLEUSER AND Jan.ROLENAME = MAY.ROLENAME
)
```

Or if you want to use a join

```
SELECT Jan.ROLEUSER, Jan.ROLENAME
  FROM Jan LEFT OUTER JOIN May ON
    Jan.ROLEUSER = MAY.ROLEUSER AND Jan.ROLENAME = MAY.ROLENAME
WHERE MAY.ROLEUSER is null
```

Comment: First query works.! It gave me both, new users and updated roles. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using a NOT IN clause with an outer reference should work.

```
SELECT Jan.ROLEUSER, Jan.ROLENAME
  FROM Jan
 WHERE Jan.ROLEUSER NOT (SELECT May.ROLEUSER FROM May)
   AND Jan.ROLEUSER NOT IN (SELECT May.ROLEUSER FROM May WHERE Jan.ROLENAME = May.ROLENAME)
```

This does the following (assuming a User has 1 record per table).

1. A User in the Jan table also exists in the May table
2. A User in the Jan table does not have the same role it did in May.
3. Returns the current User and Role in the Jan table.

Comment: I don't understand  the logic of suggested solution. So what I need : user will be the same in January as it was in May of last year but the role has to change. I need values from January table

Comment: Can you explain more about the contents of the table? For example, in January, does user abc123 have more than one record (i.e. can a user have multiple roles)?

Comment: Yes. So users will have multiple roles in both months. Some of them might be the same, some might be additional or removed.